# Regex : search for text sourrouded by specific chars, and then by specific tags

Tags: regex

I want to find all texts sourrounded by "#" char, and inside <script> tags.
How would you go about that ? For example in:

```
awoie awiefaow <script type="javascript"> #bla#ff awa </script> fawe aaa#bla1# <script>awa #bla2# aa</script>ff
```

the regex should find only #bla# and #bla2#.

I've come up with somehting like:

```
(?i)(?s)((?<=&lt;script.&#42;?>.&#42;?)#.&#42;?#(?=.&#42;?&lt;/script.&#42;?>))
```

but that would also return #bla1#.

What would be good way to aproach this problem ? or is there something more flexible for advanced text searching in multiple files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This C# example uses lookbehinds.

```
string input =@"awoie awiefaow <script type=""javascript""> #bla#ff awa </script> fawe aaa#bla1# <script>awa #bla2# aa #bla3# aa</script>ff";
string pattern = @"(?<=<script[^>]*>(?:(?!</script>)(?:[^#]|#(?:(?!</script>)[^#])*#))*#)([^#]*)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches (input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Yields:

```
Match[0] => bla
Match[1] => bla2
Match[2] => bla3
```